# Why writing $[X,Y]_t$ as $dX_t dY_t$ is so called "abuse of notation"

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Why writing $d[X,Y]_t$ as $dX_t dY_t$ or $[B]_t$ as $\int_0^tdt$ is so called "abuse of notation"?

Is it because $[B]_t \rightarrow \int_0^tdt$ a.s. but they are not equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is not really an abuse of notation but the former is. Here is why. Suppose you want to compute the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral
$$\int H_s d[X,Y]_s$$
for some process $H$. Now by that notation it may look like there is a double stochastic integral involved here but there is not. The notation is meant as a kind of multiplication rule when computing the quadratic covariation process. The actual "multiplication" rule is as follows.
$$[\int M_s dW_s, \int N_s dZ_s] = \int M_sN_s d[W,Z]_s$$
Now let $X$ denote the first term on the LHS and $Y$ the second term. Now we work out $d[X,Y]$ and $dXdY$ (as if we are multiplying).

$$d[X,Y]_s = M_sN_s d[W,Z]_s$$
$$dX_sdY_s = M_sN_s dW_sdZ_s$$

Now I hope the analogy is clear.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand "The notation is meant as a kind of multiplication rule when computing the quadratic covariation process."

Comment: @luka5z I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually $[B]_t=\int_0^tdt$ is also incorrect, but for a different reason...

Comment: @Did Is it incorrect because the integrator and the upper limit have the same symbol? (because I sort of ignored that)

Comment: Precisely. Not as much a big deal as what you explain.